# Fastest "trivial" way of shuffling a vector

Tags: c++, shuffle

I am working on a chess engine for some time now. For improving the engine, I wrote some code which loads chess-positions from memory into some tuner code. I have around 1.85B fens on my machine which adds up to 40Gb (24B per position).

After loading, I end up with a vector of positions:

```cpp
struct Position{
   std::bitset<8*24> bits{};
}

void main(){
    std::vector<Position> positions{};
   
    // mimic some data loading
    for(int i = 0; i < 1.85e9; i++){
        positions.push_back(Position{})
    }    

    // ...
}
```

The data is organised in the following way:

> The positions are taken from games where the positions are seperated by just a few moves. Usually about 40-50 consecutive moves come the same game / line and are therefor somewhat equal.

Eventually I will read 16384 position within a single batch and ideally none of those positions come from the same game. Therefor I do some initial sorting before using the data.

My current shuffling method is this:

```cpp
    auto rng = std::default_random_engine {};
    std::shuffle(std::begin(positions), std::end(positions), rng);
```

Unfortunately this takes quiet some time (about 1-2 minutes). Since I dont require perfect shuffles, I assume that some easier shuffles exist.

My second aproach was:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++){
        std::swap(positions[i], positions[(i*16384) % positions.size()]);
    }
```

which will ensure that there are not going to be positions coming from the same game within a single batch and are evenly spaces by 16384 entries.

I was wondering if there is some even simpler, faster solution. Especially considering that the modulo-operator requires quiet some clock cycles.

I am happy for any "trivial" solution.

Greetings
Finn

Comment: `std::shuffle` is already optimal. See the [possible implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle#Possible_implementation)

Comment: optimal in terms of what? Ideally I get rid of rand() or any calls that may slow down at all and purely rely on some quick/dirty index computation which ensures no positions from a game are close to each otehr

Comment: In that does one swap per element. You can pass whatever generator you like to it, e.g. one that does the equivalent of `i*16384`

Comment: First, the default random engine may be a "high-quality" engine, which means that it is relatively slow. You can use some fast less-quality engines, such as [xorshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift). Second, have you considered multi-threaded shuffling? For instance, the libstdc++ parallel mode seems to provide [such an algorithm](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/parallel/random_shuffle.h) (build upon OpenMP).

Comment: @DanielLangr No I have not considered MT-shuffling. Can you make an example?

Comment: @FinnEggers AFAIK, there is no solution in the C++ standard library. You need to use either some third-party solution (such as mentioned libstdc++ parallel mode), or implement your own. Just look for "parallel shuffle algorithm". For instance, this paper might be relevant: http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-2113/paper3.pdf.

Comment: Your second approach looks like what I would call a pseudo-random interleaver. As an example, you can try a google search with the term *s-random interleaver*. But most rather good pseudo-random interleavers that I know rely on some modulo operation ...  Note that the modulo operation is likely to be faster if the size is a known (at compile time) power of two value.

Comment: @Damien yes I know that but sadly the closest power of 2 is very far off. I cannot rely on shifts here. But I will do some further research and the solutions below are already quiet good :)

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://thompsonsed.co.uk/random-number-generators-for-c-performance-tested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a tradeoff to be made: Shuffling a a `std::vector<size_t>` of indices can be expected to be cheaper than shuffling a `std::vector<Position>` at the cost of an indirection when accessing the `Position`s via shuffled indices. Actually the example on cppreference for [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) is doing something along that line (it uses iterators):

> ```
> #include <algorithm>
> #include <iostream>
> #include <list>
> #include <numeric>
> #include <random>
> #include <vector>
>  
> int main()
> {
>     std::list<int> l(10);
>     std::iota(l.begin(), l.end(), -4);
>  
>     std::vector<std::list<int>::iterator> v(l.size());
>     std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), l.begin());
>  
>     std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});
>  
>     std::cout << "Contents of the list: ";
>     for(auto n: l) std::cout << n << ' ';
>     std::cout << '\n';
>  
>     std::cout << "Contents of the list, shuffled: ";
>     for(auto i: v) std::cout << *i << ' ';
>     std::cout << '\n';
> }
> ```

Instead of shuffling the list directly, a vector of iterators (with a `std::vector` indices woud work as well) is shuffled and `std::shuffle` only needs to swap iterators (/indices) rather than the more costly actual elements (in the example the "costly to swap" elements are just `int`s).

For a `std::list` I don't expect a big difference between iterating in order or iterating via shuffled iterators. On the other hand, for a `std::vector` I do expect a significant impact. Hence, I would shuffle indices, then rearrange the vector once, and profile to see which performs better.

---

PS: As noted in comments, `std::shuffle` is already the optimal algorithm to shuffle a range of elements. However, note that it swaps each element twice on average (possible implementation from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)):

> ```
> for (diff_t i = n-1; i > 0; --i) {
>         using std::swap;
>         swap(first[i], first[D(g, param_t(0, i))]);
> ```

On the other hand, shuffling the indices and then rearranging the vector only requires to copy/move each element once (when additional memory is available).

Comment: @Caleth sounds reasonable, though even then shuffling a `std::vector<size_t>` can be expected to be faster because more elements fit into same memory

Comment: This is a pretty clevere solution although i expect the marseine-twister to be somewhat slower, no?

Comment: @FinnEggers in many implementations `std::default_random_engine` is an alias for `std::mt19937`

Comment: @FinnEggers this is just the cppreference example literally. Hence also `std::list` instead of a vector.

Answer (score 2):

Randomness won't guarantee that samplings don't get positions from the same game which you wanted to avoid. I propose following pseudo-shuffle that does prevent samplings from the same game (given sufficiently large population):

- let N be the length of the longest game + 1
- let E be iterator to the end
- let i be random index
- while E != begin

  - if i > E - begin

    - i %= E - begin
    - --N
  - Swap elements at i and std::prev(E)
  - Decrement E
  - i += N

Comment: I need to iterate over the shuffled vector more than once so i would prefer shuffling it once and then using the shuffled data

Comment: @FinnEggers Even if you iterate it 100 times, wouldn't iterating 16000 * 100 times be faster than shuffling 1.8 billion items?

Comment: @FinnEggers `sample` copies into an output iterator. You'd iterate over a different container than the population

Comment: @FinnEggers I re-wrote the answer to suggest alternative "shuffle"